# Trying to set a source intensity rate in hours but it is in per second

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to set the source rate from a schedule object.
The model time is - hours. The schedule value is in 1. But when I run a model, it gives me the source intensity rate of 1 per second.

[image]

Could you please help me to understand where I am doing wrong with model settings or with code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your source "Arrival defined by" as Rate Schedule"

and then select your schedule object

[image]

The source will then show that the 'Arrival Type" is of `rate schedule`

[image]